# No encuentro la forma de saltar varias lineas de un archivo csv

Tags: python, csv

Necesito escribir una función que lea el archivo y me entregue como resultado un diccionario donde los datos sean accesibles usando los nombres de las columnas.

[image: Forma original del csv]

*edit*
Pude crear el diccionario que necesitaba, pero a partir de un archivo csv modificado, diferente al original.
éste es el codigo que use para crear el diccionario:

```py
datos = csv.DictReader(open(r'C:\Users\marti\planet_data-copia.csv'), fieldnames=())

dict_planetas = {}
for row in datos:
    for column, value in row.items():
               dict_planetas.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print(dict_planetas)
```

El archivo que use en éste caso es diferente, ya que elimine las filas que empezaban por #, quedando en A1, la fila que tiene los keys del futuro diccionario.
Mi duda ahora es como puedo, a partir de la forma del csv original, indicar al código que tome la informacíon a partir de cierta línea, e "ignore" por así decirlo, la información que está en las líneas superiores.

Comment: Te la escribo de inmediato; sólo dejame tipear el ejemplo que pones. Con letra tan chica me cuesta distinguir y a veces se me corre la línea.

Comment: Sinceramente, no entiendo como no te encontraste con el modulo csv durante tu investigacion. Es justo lo que buscas. Sobre lo que dijo Candid moe, tal vez no lo dijo del mejor modo, pero piensa en que no tenemos ganas y/o tiempo de ponernos a transcribir un csv letra por letra. Si quieres aumentar tus posibilidades de tener respuesta, te recomiendo editar la pregunta y colocar el csv como texto (no es necesario que sea real, con un ejemplo alacanza). Asi es, para ambos lados, simplemente copiar y pegar para probar.

Comment: @DanteS. Finalmente me enteré del modulo csv y pude realizar lo que quería, pero ahora me encontré con otro problema que me temía. Lo dejé en la edicion de la pregunta. Con respecto a lo del csv como texto; pido perdón, no me di cuenta que lo incluí como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí un ejemplo que funcionaría. Simulando leer un csv con Stringio (en ese punto sustituír con open....

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

ejemplo = """#col1 aa
#col2 bb
#col3 cc
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,6,4
"""

def leerlineas():
    lines = StringIO(ejemplo)  # acá sería lines = open....
    for line in lines:
        if line[0] != "#":
            yield line
            break
    yield from lines

result = csv.DictReader(leerlineas())

list(result)

# [{'col1': '1', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3'},
# {'col1': '4', 'col2': '6', 'col3': '4'}]
```